# All Put & Delete route method Throw 302 error in my laravel vue js project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm developing a laravel vue js application. Here I have a problem that all put & Delete method are throwing 302 error

this is my localhost response [image]

this is my server response [image]

Everything is running perfectly on my local pc but when I'm uploading this to the server then only get and post method working perfectly. Put & delete method throwing 302 error.

My route

```
Route::apiResource('category','CategoryController');
```

My Controller

```
 public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = Str::slug($request->name);
        $category->save();
    }
```

My Vue Component(I'm using V-form)

```
updateData() {
                if (this.$middleware.admin()) {
                    this.$Progress.start();
                    this.form.put('api/category/' + this.form.id)
                        .then(() => {
                            Fire.$emit('getCategory');
                            $('#modal').modal('hide');
                            Toast.fire({
                                icon: 'success',
                                title: 'Category Updated successfully',
                            });
                            this.$Progress.finish();
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            this.$Progress.fail();
                        });
                }
            },
```

Comment: 302 doesnt mean error, it's just mean redirect, the real error is 403, which mean forbidden

Comment: I'm return nothing then why its redirect.

Comment: 403 error https://i.postimg.cc/7YxLfZVS/403.png

Comment: 403 error details https://i.postimg.cc/MKPzHbX8/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

Try spoofing your method by adding `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` to your form.

Or you could add `_method: "PUT",` to your component's `form` definition.

Take a look at the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing